# How to configure Firebase hosting to use pug instead of html file?

Tags: node.js, firebase, pug, firebase-hosting

I want to hosting my webapp to firebase hosting but it seems that firebase doesn't work with pug template because it return me 404 page not found with my "index.pug".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting won't compile any sort of frameworks or templates for you.  It just serves static content.  If you want to use a pug template, you'll have to compile it, then move the static assets into the Firebase Hosting public directory.

Comment: A fun example of such an app is https:firebase.events, which we generate from a pug template + data from the Firebase database, and the generated static content is then deployed to Firebase Hosting.

Answer (score 1):

tested as of 2020-05-16. `express + pug` works on firebase hosting.

a few notes :

- test with a private window of your browser ;
- after you deploy, it may take a couple more seconds for the pug page to be available. i'm from Hongkong while i'm deploying the functions to the default location `us-central`, not sure if this is related though ;
- the view you submit to "res.render", for example, make sure it's `index` and NOT `/index` ;

try these :

`[project folder root]/functions/`**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

//###############################################################
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

//###############################################################
app.get("/index", function(req, res, next){
  res.render("index", {title:"title lo, rendered from index.js"});
});

app.get("/page/:page_num", function(req, res, next){
  const page_num = req.params.page_num;
  res.render("page", {title:"page here", page_num: page_num});
});

// export to firebase functions
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

`[project folder root]/functions/views/`**index.pug**

```
h1 okok hello from pug
p this is a line
p another line here
p here is the title : #{title}
```

`[project folder root]/functions/views/`**page.pug**

```
h1 page 
p this is page title : #{title}
p this is page number : #{page_num}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that you should use cloud functions. You can use `handlebars` or `pug`. Here it is an example using `handlebars`.

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/template-handlebars

I haven't used `pug`, but it should be in the same way that `handlebars`.
You should divide the dynamic files in the functions folder (`pug files` goes there under views) and your `CSS` and `JS` should be in the public folder. The public only serves static content.

There is a really good video to get a step by step guide (also you can learn about `CDN` and `caching content`) here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8